# Searching for a word nearly describing "how alive something is"; synonym just out of reach

Tags: nouns, synonyms

A distinguished colleague and I have been scouring our resources for a noun which correctly articulates the distinction between a pangolin and a croissant.  *Exempli gratia*, one is alive, the other is not, yet both would be on a spectrum which this word describes, henceforth the two are related by this elusive word.

Nouns broaching the concept we desire to convey include:

- Liveliness
- Corporeality
- Sentience
- Cognizance
- Mortality

Yet each of the aforementioned words fall short of a satisfactory definition.

Example usage:

Man (or woman): "That looks like a croissant."
Woman (or man): "I'd say it's a pangolin, but who am I to assume its [__________]?"

This example was adapted from a recent conversation which was ground to a startling halt due to our collective lack of knowledge and comprehension of the English language. Our conundrum has severely impeded our ability communicate, to the point at which we must humbly grasp in desperation into this vast hive mind of linguaphiles for an answer.

We thank you dearly, with the kindest sincerity.

Comment: I believe the usual term in linguistics is [*animacy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy).

Comment: That little mammal looks nothing like a croissant. Even if they looked alike, one is an animal, the other is a pastry. I think you are unnecessarily complicating the matter.

Comment: @StoneyB - I appreciate learning something new, but I can't help thinking now that it's the linguists who have unnecessarily complicated the matter.  ;0)

Comment: @StoneyB this is the exact word we were seeking.  You have put our minds at ease and freed our conversation to continue on to more important matters.  Now please write your response as an answer so I can give you full credit for its correctness!

Comment: Vitality {From [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vitality): '1b. The characteristic, principle, or force that distinguishes living things from nonliving things.'} Collins gives 'a less common term for [_vital force_](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vital-force)'. But this sense is swamped by the more common one and sounds at best strange / pompous.

Comment: I like both the suggestions you've got here. Though in you sample sentence I'd replace "assume" with "judge". If that's really the sentence in which you want to use the word, then I'm guessing it's intended to be humourous (it made me smile). The resemblance between a croissant and a pagnolin is close enough for humour but as per @MarkDWorthenPsyD's comment, perhaps little else, unless the two characters are aliens ... When it becomes more believable but retains the humour.

Comment: I have slathered my pangolin in Confiture de groseilles de Bar-le-Duc, and yet she does not inspire my appetite. Have I misapprehended the nature of the investigation?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you're right with vitality. Animacy focuses on sentience. Plants lack animacy but retain vitality - I think this is how many people would read the difference.

Comment: @PatrickKeenan In linguistics *animacy* tends to focus on the capacity for agency quite as much as sentience, or even more.

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD The linguists don't complicate the matter: the languages they study exhibit the complexity.

Comment: @StoneyB I find the article you link to informative and largely in line with my take on the meanings of 'life'.

Comment: @StoneyB, agency implies sentience - you're typing at a linguist :P In any case the croissant isn't agentive or sentient so I still think vitality is the better choice. Also I don't think we can be so definitive about the language vs. the linguist introducing the complexity. A language is data, linguists interpret that data, and in that interpretation there's a fallible component whereby we may be the introducers of the complexity.

Comment: @StoneyB - Well said. I was trying to inject a bit of humour into the discussion. But as my teenage daughter would tell me, "Complete fail."

Comment: Having been educated, I upvoted this question.

Comment: @PatrickKeenan I'm an amateur; but it seems to me linguists (or proto-linguists) like Aristotle and Aquinas have been arguing about agency and sentience for 2500 years now! ... But *vitality* in linguistics seems to have been pre-empted by the folks who worry about language survival.

Comment: "zest" isn't a bad word... doesn't mean "sentient' but it has traits of relishing liveliness https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/zest

Comment: I recommend against taking the bait.

Comment: I think there's no such scale, even if the only evidence of that lack is that *20 Questions* invariably starts with *Animal, vegetable or mineral?*

Some of the suggestions here might serve but none seems to really shriek its suitability.

I suspect that's the other side of the dilemma Lyall Watson used the whole of *The Romeo Error* to explore: no definition of life does not clearly apply to some obviously dead objects, and vice versa.

*Pangolin* and *croissant* might be far enough apart to make useful distinctions but that doesn't say there's a scale which encompasses everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I do think that **sentient** / **sentience** perfectly fits the bill. However, I can see a reason why you'd think it's not quite correct.

---

### Why I think it's correct

What is sentience?

> - **Wikipedia** - Sentience is the capacity to feel, perceive, or experience subjectively.
> - **Dictionary.com** - condition or character; capacity for sensation or feeling.
> - **Merriam-Webster** - feeling or sensation as distinguished from perception and thought
> - **Oxford** - Able to perceive or feel things.

That sounds to me like the definition of being alive. I could elaborate on this further, but I think my argument here is clear (feel free to comment if you disagree): **being alive means experiencing/perceiving things**.

---

### Why you might think it's incorrect

This is of course an assumption based on your question.

Technically, sentience speaks to the cognitive capacities of the object, as opposed to its "being alive".

From that perspective, I can understand that you consider sentience to not necessarily be *wrong*, but rather to be focusing on something different than what you're focusing on.

(this is my opinion) I think that these are two sides of the same coin. They are synonymous, and there is no practical difference between the two and there is no point to ever differentiate between the two.
And if there's no distinction to be made (alleged by me), then they are functionally synonymous, and therefore it is correct to use "sentient" to describe that something is alive.

---